# IRC Connection reset by peer in VMWare?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I am currently running a Ubuntu (Guest) in VMWare and I'm trying to connect to irc.freenode.net.  I've installed an IRC client on my host PC and I can connect via the host, but when I try to on my Guest I get the following...

```
11:19 -!- Irssi: Connecting to irc.freenode.net [185.30.166.37] port 6667
11:19 -!- Irssi: Connection to irc.freenode.net established
11:19 -!- Irssi: warning Connection reset by peer
11:19 -!- Irssi: Connection lost to irc.freenode.net
```

I'm also using a bridged connection with my Guest/Host at the moment.  I'm unsure why the connection happens and then gets reset on the guest any ideas?

Comment: Could you try if connecting to `holmes.freenode.net` produces the same output?

Comment: @nkn Same results

Comment: for some reason it appears I can connect to `irc.ubuntu.com` -- but none of the others I have tried.

Comment: The irc.ubuntu.com option no longer works either... ;-/  anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was solved by adding `use_tls = "yes";` into FreeNode configuration under "servers" in ~/.irssi/config.